# pytest fixture of fixture, not found

Tags: python, pytest

Based on this stackoverflow: [pytest fixture of fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777854/pytest-fixture-of-fixtures)

I have the following code in the same file:

```
@pytest.fixture
def form_data():
    return { ... }

@pytest.fixture
def example_event(form_data):
    return {... 'data': form_data, ... }
```

But when I run pytest, it complains that `fixture 'form_data' not found`

I am new to pytest so I am not even sure if this is possible?

Comment: Can you share the code of final test at where you are using the fixture `example_event`?

Comment: Why did you accept the answer @JamesLin, given it does not solve your problem? Did you discover something else that you can clarify for others?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

If you have the test and all the fixtures in 1 file:
`test.py`

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    return "foo"

@pytest.fixture
def bar(foo):
    return foo, "bar"

def test_foo_bar(bar):
    expected = ("foo", "bar")
    assert bar == expected
```

and run `pytest test.py` then Success!!!

```
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-4.3.0
collected 1 item                                                                                   

test.py .                                                                                    [100%]

===================================== 1 passed in 0.02 seconds =====================================
```

But if you put the fixtures in a different file: `test_foo_bar.py`

```
from test import bar

def test_foo_bar(bar):
    expected = ("foo", "bar")
    assert bar == expected
```

and run `pytest test_foo_bar.py` expecting (like I did) that importing only the `bar` fixture is enough since on importing it would already have executed the `foo` fixture then you get the error you are getting.

```
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-4.3.0
collected 1 item                                                                                   

test2.py E                                                                                   [100%]

============================================== ERRORS ==============================================
__________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_foo_bar __________________________________
file .../test_foo_bar.py, line 3
  def test_foo_bar(bar):
.../test.py, line 7
  @pytest.fixture
  def bar(foo):
E       fixture 'foo' not found
>       available fixtures: TIMEOUT, bar, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, cov, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, no_cover, once_without_docker, pytestconfig, record_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

.../test.py:7
===================================== 1 error in 0.03 seconds ======================================
```

To fix this also import the `foo` fixture in the `test_foo_bar.py` module.

Comment: Worth mentioning: pytest supports a `conftest.py` file to share fixtures across files, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files

Comment: I've got a simple fixture defined in the **same file** and it *still* reports "not found" - but it works if I define them in the *separate* `conftest.py` (same directory). This problem is the same as described by the OP. But your solution, @m.bron, does not answer this problem, as you seem to think the problem can only occur if the fixtures are defined in a separate file, which is not the case for the OP or for me. I don't know why this answer has been accepted.