# How to pass a list of fixtures to a test case in Pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, iterable, pytest-fixtures

I have a case where I need a list of fixtures (similar ones) inside a test case and perform same operation with those fixtures.

**For ex:**

```
def testcase(fixture1, fixture2, fixture3):
    # do some operation with fixture1
    # do the same operation with fixture2
    # do the same operation with fixture3
```

The thing is I have multiple such fixtures. Around 15 or so.
I'm looking for a way where I can mention these fixtures in a list like
`fixtures_list = [fixture1, fixture2, fixture3, ...]`
and update the list whenever needed.

And use a for loop inside the test case to perform operations on with the fixture like

```
for fixture in fixtures_list:
    #do something with fixture
```

But I'm unable to do it as we must definitely pass the fixture to the test case.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777854/pytest-fixture-of-fixtures)

Comment: Something similar worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by creating another fixture and returning the fixtures inside that fixture.

```
def fixture_that_returns_other_fixtures(fix1, fix2, fix3):
    return fix1, fix2, fix3
```

and used `fixture_that_returns_other_fixtures` in all other tests wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

From the pytest doc [Here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#back-to-fixtures):

```
import pytest


class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name


@pytest.fixture
def my_fruit():
    return Fruit("apple")


@pytest.fixture
def fruit_basket(my_fruit):
    return [Fruit("banana"), my_fruit]


def test_my_fruit_in_basket(my_fruit, fruit_basket):
    assert my_fruit in fruit_basket
```

Assuming this example and what you want, you can juste create a new fixture that takes your fixtures as parameters, and return them in a list.

Here is the same test, written with the appropriate solution:

```
@pytest.fixture
def all_fixtures(my_fruit, fruit_basket):
    return [my_fruit, fruit_basket]

def test_my_fruit_in_basket_bis(all_fixtures):
    assert all_fixtures[0] in all_fixtures[1]
```